# Code for Log Out Button Yields Strange URL

Tags: login

I'm using some code that I found [here](http://php-mysql-guide.blogspot.com/2012/02/add-login-form-on-wordpress-theme.html) in order to create a login/logout form on my sidebar. The login works just fine, but what's weird is that on logout, the user gets redirected to "personaldomain.com/%2F", and I get an error that says

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL // was not found on this server.

The code for the logout button is:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>">logout</a><br />
```

Any advice?

Comment: What happens if you do not use `urlencode()` which is used anyway in `wp_logout_url()`s internal code?

Answer (score 2):

According to the codex.. this part:

```
urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

.
**is unneeded... if you just wan't to logout** (pasting from [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url))

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

.

**Logout and Redirect to Current Page**

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

.
**Logout and Redirect to Homepage**

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

.
Hope this helps... should always check the codex first ;)

Have a gr8 day,
Sagive